# Trimble Nomad and ArcPad gwes.exe Error

Tags: arcpad, windows-8, trimble

On my Trimble Nomad, I have ArcPad 8 and windows mobile 8. The handheld has been working great up until recently. The machine has been very choppy and slow and when I go to add a point or really do anything I receive the window mobile gwes[image].exe error.

ESRI help hasn't been able to find a solution. Has anyone seen this before and found a work around or an actual fix?

Comment: potentially a low memory issue https://geonet.esri.com/thread/46457

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with your device running out of memory.

To confirm this - Switch on the Status Bar and double-tap the status bar in the bottom-right corner. This should bring up your Memory Status Indicator on your map. Keep an eye on the memory indicator when your device starts performing poorly.

If running out of memory is your issue - follow [these tips](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/How_to_make_your_map_draw_faster/00s1000000wm000000/) to make your mobile project perform better.